# How to insert byte array into Informix blob

Tags: jdbc, informix

How should I insert big byte array into an Informix blob column? Now I have query:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE (COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN3, COLUMN4, COLUMN_BLOB)
    VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

which throws a really weird exception:

```
org.sqlproc.engine.SqlProcessorException: SQL '  INSERT INTO TABLE (COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN3, COLUMN4, COLOMN_BLOB   )   VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)'. org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar []; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: The specified table (into) is not in the database.
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: The specified table (into) is not in the database.
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.a(IfxSqli.java:3545)
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.E(IfxSqli.java:3871)
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.dispatchMsg(IfxSqli.java:2661)
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.receiveMessage(IfxSqli.java:2577)
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.executeFastPath(IfxSqli.java:5981)
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.executeFastPath(IfxSqli.java:5892)
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSmartBlob.IfxLoColInfo(IfxSmartBlob.java:306)
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSmBlob.i(IfxSmBlob.java:787)
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSmBlob.a(IfxSmBlob.java:520)
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxResultSet.b(IfxResultSet.java:291)
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxStatement.c(IfxStatement.java:1275)
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(IfxPreparedStatement.java:418)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:105)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:105)
    at org.sqlproc.engine.spring.SpringQuery$9.doInPreparedStatement(SpringQuery.java:454)
    at org.sqlproc.engine.spring.SpringQuery$9.doInPreparedStatement(SpringQuery.java:448)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:587)
    ... 44 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ISAM error: no record found.
    at com.informix.util.IfxErrMsg.getSQLException(IfxErrMsg.java:412)
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.E(IfxSqli.java:3876)
    ... 59 more
```

I am using [`sqlProcessor`](https://github.com/hudec/sql-processor/wiki) which uses a prepared statement to insert the blob into table:

```
@Override
public void set(PreparedStatement st, int index, Object value) throws SQLException {
    byte[] bytes = (byte[]) value;
    st.setBytes(index, bytes);
}
```

DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
  COLUMN1 BIGINT ,
  COLUMN2 VARCHAR(30) ,
  COLUMN3 INTEGER ,
  COLUMN4 INTEGER ,
  COLUMN_BLOB blob 
);
```

The Informix server is Informix 12.10 running on AIX 7.1.

**UPDATE**

Ok I solve first problem. The sql starts with space which is proprably problem for informix. But now I have another exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: PreparedStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL []; SQL state [IX000]; error code [-9810]; Smart-large-object error.; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Smart-large-object error.
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:83)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:80)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:80)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:603)
    at org.sqlproc.engine.spring.SpringQuery.updateWithoutGenKeys(SpringQuery.java:448)
    at org.sqlproc.engine.spring.SpringQuery.update(SpringQuery.java:293)
    ... 42 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Smart-large-object error.
    at com.informix.util.IfxErrMsg.getSQLException(IfxErrMsg.java:412)
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.a(IfxSqli.java:3549)
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.E(IfxSqli.java:3871)
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.dispatchMsg(IfxSqli.java:2661)
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.receiveMessage(IfxSqli.java:2577)
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.executeFastPath(IfxSqli.java:5981)
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.executeFastPath(IfxSqli.java:5892)
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSmartBlob.IfxLoCreate(IfxSmartBlob.java:376)
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSmBlob.i(IfxSmBlob.java:790)
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSmBlob.a(IfxSmBlob.java:520)
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxResultSet.b(IfxResultSet.java:291)
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxStatement.c(IfxStatement.java:1275)
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(IfxPreparedStatement.java:418)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:105)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:105)
    at org.sqlproc.engine.spring.SpringQuery$9.doInPreparedStatement(SpringQuery.java:454)
    at org.sqlproc.engine.spring.SpringQuery$9.doInPreparedStatement(SpringQuery.java:448)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:587)
    ... 44 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Smart Large Objects: No sbspace number specified.
    at com.informix.util.IfxErrMsg.getSQLException(IfxErrMsg.java:412)
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.E(IfxSqli.java:3876)
    ... 59 more
```

Comment: Are you able to insert data without last BLOB column? Also show us how is this column defined. What kind of `BLOB` do you use? Create simple example with `CREATE TABLE`, two columns and `INSERT`. Show us Informix version and JDBC driver version.

Comment: ddl updated. WHen I miss blobl column inserting works fine and when I want to add just blol exception is same

Comment: what you mean with platform and version ? I am using informix db version 12.10

Comment: That's what I mean: which version of Informix server (12.10 you said), which version of Informix JDBC driver (probably the version shipped with CSDK 4.10) and which O/S are you running it on?  I'm no JDBC expert, but the error message given (plus the fact that it works when you omit the BLOB column) suggests something seriously wrong; I recommend contacting your support channels (ultimately, IBM/Informix Tech Support) for advice.

Comment: hm I am not sure. AIX Version 7.1 this can be which you want ?

Comment: Ugh...I'm under-caffeinated: this is BLOB column, not a BYTE column.  I've deleted my previous remarks about `locator_t` and rewrites because they only apply to BYTE or TEXT (dumb) blobs, not BLOB or CLOB (smart) blobs.  And the usurping of the old term for BYTE and TEXT as a new type still causes irritation (though I should be used to it by now).

Comment: What if version of your JDBC driver? In Jython code from my response you will see how to obtain it from `Conenction` object.

Comment: From discussion at http://informix.questionfor.info/q_informix_57173.html it seems that upgrading JDBC driver may help. Also check default `SBSPACENAME` in the onconfig file as mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

I created similar table and simple Jython program that test both inserting into `BLOB` column and selecting from it.

As test data I used GIF file with snoopy cartoon :-)

```
#!/usr/bin/env jython
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-

import time

from java.sql import DriverManager
from java.lang import Class
from java.io import FileInputStream
from java.io import ByteArrayOutputStream

Class.forName("com.informix.jdbc.IfxDriver")

"""
create table _blob_test_so (
    id serial,
    txt varchar(30),
    column_blob blob
);
"""

def test_blob_insert(db):
    print('inserting gif picture into blob table...')
    blob = FileInputStream('snoopy_comics20121023.gif')
    insert_stmt = db.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO _blob_test_so (txt, column_blob) VALUES (?, ?)")
    insert_stmt.setString(1, 'test %s' % (time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')))
    insert_stmt.setBinaryStream(2, blob)
    #insert_stmt.setBytes(2, [0, 1, 2, 3])
    rec_cnt = insert_stmt.executeUpdate()
    blob.close()
    print('records changed: %d' % (rec_cnt))

def test_blob_select(db):
    print('selecting data from blob table...')
    pstm = db.prepareStatement("SELECT id, txt, column_blob FROM _blob_test_so")
    rs = pstm.executeQuery()
    while (rs.next()):
        id = rs.getInt(1)
        txt = rs.getString(2)
        image_stream = rs.getBinaryStream(3)
        fout = ByteArrayOutputStream()
        while 1:
            b = image_stream.read()
            if b < 0:
                break
            fout.write(b)
        arr = fout.toByteArray()
        fname_out = 'test_%s.gif' % (id)
        print('%d:%s: fname: %s %d [b]' % (id, txt, fname_out, len(arr)))
        f = open(fname_out, 'wb')
        f.write(arr)
        f.close()

def test_version(db):
    try:
        dbmi = db.getMetaData();
        print('-' * 10)
        print("JDBC driver version is '%s'; major: %s; minor: %s" % (dbmi.getDriverVersion(), dbmi.getDriverMajorVersion(), dbmi.getDriverMinorVersion()));
        c = db.createStatement()
        rs = c.executeQuery("SELECT FIRST 1 DBINFO('version','full') FROM systables")
        while (rs.next()):
            print("Server version: '%s'" % (rs.getString(1)))
    except:
        print("there were errors!")
        s = traceback.format_exc()
        sys.stderr.write("%s\n" % (s))


db = DriverManager.getConnection('jdbc:informix-sqli://test-informix/test:informixserver=ol_testifx;DB_LOCALE=pl_PL.CP1250;CLIENT_LOCALE=pl_PL.CP1250;charSet=CP1250', 'informix', 'informix')
test_version(db)
test_blob_insert(db)
test_blob_select(db)
```

I use Jython 2.5.3 on java1.7.0_51. and in my environment it works well. It reports that I use:

```
JDBC driver version is '4.10.JC2DE'; major: 4; minor: 10
Server version: 'IBM Informix Dynamic Server Version 11.50.FC4    '
```

It creates `test_*.gif` files that are identical to `snoopy_comics20121023.gif`.

So my conclusion is that there is problem in your environment. I suspect JDBC driver.

Comment: check my update. I am using setBytes to store blob no setBinaryStream as you

Comment: When I changed `setBinaryStream()` into `insert_stmt.setBytes(2, [0, 1, 2, 3])` it still works. Of course now I do not receive GIF file, but result file consist os 4 bytes: `00 01 02 03` as requested. Shortly: works for me.

Comment: I still think there is problem with JDBC driver. See: http://informix.questionfor.info/q_informix_57173.html

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, this happens when no temporary sb-space has been defined.

An example on how to create the sb-space is here:

```
onspaces -c -S sbddbs -p /infentw/sbdbs01.dat -o 0 -s 1000000
onbar -b -F
```

It must also be added to $ONCONFIG:

```
SBSPACENAME     sbddbs       # Default smartblob space name
```

Finally you must restart the informix server.

```
onmode -ky; oninit -v
```